# Change text color based on td value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a table that returns values from my Mysql database without issue.  What I want to do is change the font color to green if two of the five values is selected from radio buttons.

The field that I wish to change the color is the "Category" field if the value is either Vegetarian or Vegan.  All other options will be the default color (black).

This is my code that displays the table data, which is displaying as I wish:

```
$richOutput = widgets\RichText::widget(['text' => $post->message,     'record' => $post]);
$richOutput_rname = widgets\RichText::widget(['text' => $post->rname, 'record' => $post]);
$richOutput_category = widgets\RichText::widget(['text' => $post->category, 'record' => $post]); ?>
<table>
<tr><td><span id="post-content-<?php echo $post->id; ?>" <?php print $richOutput; ?></span></font></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="post-content-rname-<?php echo $post->id; ?>" <?php print $richOutput_rname; ?></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="post-content-category-<?php echo $post->id; ?>" <?php print $richOutput_category; ?></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance!

### Edit

I tried to add the following JS, but it did not change the text color when the value = "Vegan":

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.cat').each(function(i, n) {
   if($(n).text() = "Vegan") $(n).css('color', '#8A1010');
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can put a simple PHP `if` condition in the `<td>` tag of the category and apply a css class or modify any style attribute. What color are you trying to set - textcolor or background color. I think textcolor.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but it should be correct. You should get the idea.

```
 <tr><td><span id="post-content-category-<?php echo $post->id; ?>" <?php $richOutput_category == "Vegan" ? echo 'style="color: #8A1010"' : echo '' ?>><?php print $richOutput_category; ?></span></td></tr>
```

Also you were missing a '>' on the span tag (all of them).

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do it is to create a CSS class and apply that to the row with PHP. From a Separation of Concerns perspective this keeps the styles (CSS) separate from your content (HTML) and behaviour (Javascript).

The stylesheet would contain:

```
.text_normal {
    color: #000;
}
.text_vegan-vegetarian {
    color: #8A1010;
}
```

Using PHP to add the class to the table row:

```
$richOutput = widgets\RichText::widget(['text' => $post->message,     'record' => $post]);
$richOutput_rname = widgets\RichText::widget(['text' => $post->rname, 'record' => $post]);
$richOutput_category = widgets\RichText::widget(['text' => $post->category, 'record' => $post]);

$class = 'text_normal';
if ($post->category == 'Vegan' || $post->category == 'Vegetarian') {
    $class = 'text_vegan-vegetarian';
}

?>
<table>
<tr><td><span id="post-content-<?php echo $post->id; ?>" <?php print $richOutput; ?></span></font></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="post-content-rname-<?php echo $post->id; ?>" <?php print $richOutput_rname; ?></span></td></tr>
<tr class="<?= $class ?>"><td><span id="post-content-category-<?php echo $post->id; ?>" <?php print $richOutput_category; ?></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Using a separate stylesheet will allow you to add a lot of other styles without making your HTML code messy. For example:

```
.text_normal {
    color: #000;
    background: #0CF;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.text_vegan-vegetarian {
    display: none;
}
```